# how to turn binary search for string recursive?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search

I have binary search working iteratively, but I would like to see how the recursive version works for strings to better understand recursion.

I have tried the mirroring the recursive binary search for integers but haven't been able to make it work.

Can anyone help out. My iterative binary search is below.

```
static void binarySearch(String[] words, String word, int left, int right)
    {
        while (left <= right) {
            int middle = left + (right - left) / 2;

            int result = word.compareTo(words[middle]);

            // Check if x is present at mid
            if (result == 0) {
                System.out.println(words[middle]);
                return;
            }

            // If x greater, ignore left half
            if (result > 0)
                left = middle + 1;

                // If x is smaller, ignore right half
            else
                right = middle - 1;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You don't want a while loop. Instead you need to call `binarySearch` again with your new values for `left` and `right`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```java
static String binarySearch(String[] words, String word, int left, int right)
    {
            if (left > right) return null;

            int middle = left + (right - left) / 2;

            int result = word.compareTo(words[middle]);

            // Check if x is present at mid
            if (result == 0) {
                return words[middle];
            }

            // If x greater, ignore left half
            if (result > 0)
                left = middle + 1;
            else
                right = middle - 1;

            return binarySearch(words, word, left, right);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried it with a word not in `words`?